# PHP/JS; Convert invisible linebreaks or newlines to html tags for printing

Tags: javascript, printing, newline

I am trying to use javascript to print out a text field from a dbase where the textfield is served by php to a textarea that has an id.  The print javascript function takes the content from the textarea using getElementById and prints it.  But here is the issue.  To display properly in the textarea, the textfield has newlines in it.  These are invisible in the textarea.  They just show up as line breaks.  (They are also invisible using PHP admin in the dbase tables.  They show up there as linebreaks as well).

However, to get the linebreaks to show up when you print the text, they need to be converted into  `<br>`.  Otherwie, you see and print a runown sentence.

I think I need to search for something in the javascript variable, perhaps \n and replace with 
  However, I can't seem to get linebreaks to display in printed page (wich is html based.)

Can anyone suggest right way to do this?  Thanks.

Flawed code:
js
f

```
unction printit(id) {
var toprint = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
toprint = toprint.replace("\n","<br>");
win = window.open();
    self.focus();
    win.document.open();
    win.document.write('<'+'html'+'><'+'head'+'><'+'style'+'>');
    win.document.write('body, td { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt;}');
    win.document.write('<'+'/'+'style'+'><'+'/'+'head'+'><'+'body'+'>');
    win.document.write(toprint); 
    win.document.write('<'+'/'+'body'+'><'+'/'+'html'+'>');
    win.document.close();
    win.print();
    win.close();
  }
```

html

```
<textarea id="textarea">A whole bunch
of text
with line breaks
goes here
</textarea><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="printit('textarea');">Print text</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably only replacing the first line break.  Try the global flag to replace them all:

```
toprint = toprint.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
```

Comment: Strangely toprint=toprint.replace... is breaking code even when commented out. It is actually nested inside if statement as follows:  if (id=="msg") { alert ("is msg");// toprint = toprint.replace(/\n/g, '<br />'); } breaks code but when I delete whole line starting with // toprint = ... it runs though it does not preserve linebreaks.

Comment: Could problem have something to do with the fact that my variable toprint is created from innerHTML and replace does not work on that, perhaps only on .value or .textContent?

Comment: Not sure what's going on with your JS, but here's a fiddle without a function that replaces how you want it:  http://jsfiddle.net/senoramor/c7NGT/

Comment: Yes this clearly works.  I put the function in and it works as well.  However, the identical code does not work on my server.  Could it be that the replace function is dependent on some version of server/host configuration or something? I am marking right cause your code works on jsfiddle but have tried it a hundred different ways on my host and does not work.

Comment: JavaScript is browser-based, so assuming you're using the same browser on both your page and the fiddle, it should work properly.  Do you perhaps have NoScript (or something similar) and it's set to block JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need it printed out exactly the way it is appearing in the text area. The textarea applies line-wrapping to its content. These are not line-break characters and cannot be *replaced* as such.

Append the content to an element with the **same width as the textarea** before priting.

i.e.

```
...
win.document.write('<'+'/'+'style'+'><'+'/'+'head'+'><'+'body'+'>');

// element with same width as textarea
win.document.write('<div style="width: '+ document.getElementById(id).offsetWidth +'px">');
win.document.write(toprint); 
win.document.write('</div>'); 

win.document.write('<'+'/'+'body'+'><'+'/'+'html'+'>');
...
```

Comment: No the textarea definitely has line breaks in it.  I went to a lot of trouble to preserve these prior to the text getting saved in the dbase.  Specifically, to get them through an url, I urlencoded them.  This is why you literally see the linebreaks when you look at the tables in PHPadmin--though you don't see \n or what causes the breaks.  You continue to see the breaks in the textarea no matter what its width, though again the \n or whatever is invisible.  I need to convert the invisible line break code into <br> which will display properly in the html preview and then get printed ok.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for displaying newline characters in HTML is using the CSS *white-space* property.